# Custom banner/logo to certain contacts only in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, email-signature

Is it possible to have a custom banner/logo in an email for a certain contact group only? It doesn't apply to everyone in general, but only to a group of 10 members.

I use Outlook 2010.

Comment: Do you mean as stationery, or as part of your signature?

Comment: Stationary? What does that mean ? I dont think it matters, I just want a special banner to be delivered to only certain contact groups. Else normal signature.

Comment: So the banner would be in place of your signature, correct?

Comment: @freginold yes, that's right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to natively have Outlook 2010 switch between two signatures depending on who the recipient is. However, you can change signatures fairly easily when composing an email.

---

### From the message pane:

- Right click on your signature (or in the white space next to it).
- A list of all available signatures will be displayed; select the one you want to use.

---

### From the ribbon:

- Click **Message** on the ribbon.
- Click **Signature**.
- Click on the signature you want to use.

---

### From the keyboard:

- Press <kbd>ALT</kbd>, <kbd>H</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd>.
- Use the up and down arrow keys to select a signature.
- Press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to apply it.

Comment: well I tried this, and it looks like its the only way to do. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

To add on @freginold 's reply, you can even create an AutoHotKey script that will do that with a push of a single or multiple buttons instead of doing the ALT + H + A + S + ENTER procedure every time.

Sorry I can't comment, that's why I placed a new answer.

Comment: Yeah. Looks like that's the only way to do as @freginold says!